# Table right of horizontal forest

Tags: forest, trees

I'm trying to make a table just right of my forest corresponding to the last link in my forrest.

My forest looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
    grow=0,
    reversed, % tree direction
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west, % edge anchors
    anchor=west,
    if n children=0{tier=word}{}
}
[\textbf{Output Devices}
    [Visual
        [Mobile
            [Simple
                [Google Cardboard]
                [Google Daydream]
                [Samsung Gear VR]
            ]
            [Stand-alone]
        ]
        [Wired
            [Room]
            [Seated]
        ]
    ]
    [Haptic
        [Body worn]
    [Multi-sensory
        [Sensics]
        [FeelReal]
        [Nirvana Mask]
    ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas? any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to get it to look like something like this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you add a `tabular` environment immediately after `\end{forest}` it will be placed to the right of the (bottom right of) `forest`. It's not really clear to me exactly where you want it though.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made it compilable and added a picture of the output I'm seeking. Hope it makes it clear

Comment: Fake it. Add a single line tabular as the final node of each branch. Add the header above the topmost node. Draw the lines around the cells. Otherwise, you have to make sure everything matches in terms of dimensions, which is a maintenance nightmare and will break if you make the slightest changes to anything at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fake it. Or spend your life trying to maintain the unmaintainable.

Make each terminal node a single-row tabular. Draw the cell borders by referring to the Forest nodes. Add headers and so on separately.

Here's one solution. Adjust the dimension for the cell width to something suitable, depending you cell and header content. I've used `1em` for demonstration purposes.

Since you didn't provide any header content in your code, I've added a single-row header with the first seven letters of the English alphabet. If you want a row above without borders (as in your image), just add another node with another tabular above `p0`. No need to adjust the line drawing, since you don't want borders.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1em}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  declare count register=count us,
  count us'=0,
}%
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    s sep'=0pt,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent, % edge anchors
    anchor=parent,
    if n children=0{
      !u.tier=word,
      tier=terminus,
      align=*{7}{C},
      no edge,
      inner sep=0pt,
      count us'+=1,
      name=p\foresteregister{count us},
    }{}
  }
  [\textbf{Output Devices}
    [Visual
        [Mobile
            [Simple
              [Google Cardboard[x&&&&&&]]
                [Google Daydream[x&&&&&&]]
                [Samsung Gear VR[x&&&&&&x]]
            ]
            [Stand-alone[&&x&&&&]]
        ]
        [Wired
            [Room[x&&&&&&]]
            [Seated[x&&&&&&]]
        ]
    ]
    [Haptic
      [Body worn[x&&&&&&]]
      [Multi-sensory
        [Sensics[x&&&&&&]]
        [FeelReal[x&&&&&&]]
        [Nirvana Mask[x&&&&&&]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \node [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] (p0) at (p1.north west) {\begin{tabular}{*{7}{C}}A&B&C&D&E&F&G\end{tabular}};
  \draw (p0.north west) rectangle (p10.south east) ;
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,7} \draw ($(p0.north west)!\i/7!(p0.north east)$) -- ($(p10.south west)!\i/7!(p10.south east)$);
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \ilast (initially 0)] in {1,...,10} \draw ($(p\i.north west)!.5!(p\ilast.south west)$) -- ($(p\i.north east)!.5!(p\ilast.south east)$)  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignment of tabular to tree]

Comment: how to have multiple lines in this tree node, e.g. instead of "Output Devices" I want to have "Output"<newline>"Devices"?